# How Can Update MySQL field Using Ajax And PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to update data where in mysql database using ajax and php.

HTML

```
<td><input type="text" class="event" name="title<?php echo $row['id']?>" id="title_id_<?php echo $row['id']?>" value="<?php echo $row['title']?>" disabled/></td>
            <td><input type="datetime" class="event" name="start<?php echo $row['id']?>" id="start_id_<?php echo $row['id']?>" value="<?php echo $row['start']?>" disabled/></td>
            <td><input type="datetime" class="event" name="end<?php echo $row['id']?>" id="end_id_<?php echo $row['id']?>" value="<?php echo $row['end']?>" disabled/></td>
            <td><div class="edit_wrapper"><a href="#" class="edit_button" id="edit-<?php echo $row['id'] ;?>"><img       src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic-1/24/edit-icon.png"/></a></td>
            <td><div class="up_wrapper"><a href="" class="up_button" id="up-<?php echo $row['id'] ;?>"><img       src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/oxygen-icons.org/oxygen/24/Actions-svn-update-icon.png"/></a></td>
            <td><div class="del_wrapper"><a href="" class="del_button" id="del-<?php echo $row['id'] ;?>"><img       src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hopstarter/button/24/Button-Delete-icon.png"/></a></td>
```

jQuery Ajax Code

```
$('.up_button').click(function(){
    var btnid=this.id;
    btnid=btnid.replace(/\D/g, '');
    btnid=parseInt(btnid, 10);
    var e_title=$('#title_id_'+btnid).val();
    var e_start=$('#start_id_'+btnid).val();
    var e_end=$('#end_id_'+btnid).val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'event_update.php',
        data:{'title':e_title , 'id':btnid , 'start':e_start, 'end': e_end},
        type: "POST",
        success: function() {
            alert("Güncelleme başarılı.");
        }
   });


});
```

Here My PHP Code(event_update.php)

```
<?php
include_once("config.php");
$id = $_POST['bid'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$start = $_POST['start'];
$end = $_POST['end'];
mysql_query("UPDATE evenement SET title=$title,start=$start,end=$end WHERE id=$id"))
mysql_close($connecDB);
?>
```

But I Couldnt update data.Can you help?

Comment: Is it giving any error..?? If ur getting any fatal error I think ur missing ;(semi colon) here _sql_query("UPDATE evenement SET title=$title,start=$start,end=$end WHERE id=$id"))_<-- here

Comment: I had realize this. ANd I fixed.But this isnt help me.

Comment: Are you sure it's not updating ? Did you look into the DB ? Or make a page refresh ? As you use Ajax the page is not refreshing by itself.. Is the alert showing ?

Comment: $_POST['bid'] should be $_POST['id'] correct?

Answer (score 1):

replace your query line by this, any non numeric entity must be enclosed.

```
   mysql_query("UPDATE evenement SET title='$title',start='$start',end='$end' WHERE id='$id'"))
```

Comment: You should also add that **mysql_*** functions are deprecated and use PDO or MySQLi

Comment: Ok Everyone.I had fixed problem using php PDO class.I didnt found mistake which I made in previous mysql query.But Now everything is ok.Thank you All of you.